# Search and replace substring in c string

Tags: c, string

i have question about search and replace sub string in another string.

I have some `str` string  with names and **** instead of year of birth, and  `mat` array of matrix(3d array) .
The matrix contains details about persons(fName, lName and year of birth).
What i need is to run over `str` and take the name(it could be first or last) and run over the matrix and find the year of that person(if there is more than one person with the same name so write the first one)

I tried:

```
void fillYears(char* mat[][M], int rowsNum, char str[MAX_INPUT]){
   char *token,*token2;
   char tmpStr[MAX_INPUT];
   int i,index = 0;
   char subStr[2] = "\n";
   strcpy(tmpStr,str);
   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(tmpStr, subStr);
   index+=strlen(token)+1;
   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) 
   {
       token2 = strtok(token, " ");
       //walk through the matrix
       for(i=0;i<rowsNum;i++){
           // check first name and last name if the same as token name
           if(strcmp(mat[i][0],token2) == 0 || strcmp(mat[i][1],token2) == 0)
           {
               str[index-5] = mat[i][2][0];
               str[index-4] = mat[i][2][1];
               str[index-3] = mat[i][2][2];
               str[index-2] = mat[i][2][3];
               break;
           }
       }

      token = strtok((str+index), subStr);
      index+=strlen(token);
   }
}

void main(){
    char * inputStr[NUM_OF_ROWS][M];
    char str[MAX_INPUT] = "aa ****\nbbb ****\ncc ****\n";
    inputStr[0][0] = "aa";
    inputStr[0][1] = "aaa";
    inputStr[0][2] = "1111";
    inputStr[1][0] = "bb";
    inputStr[1][1] = "bbb";
    inputStr[1][2] = "2222";
    inputStr[2][0] = "cc";
    inputStr[2][1] = "ccc";
    inputStr[2][2] = "3333";
    fillYears(inputStr,3,str);
}
```

In the first 2 names i find the year and replace **** in `str` with the year, but in the third one i get error.

Pleas help.

Comment: Better approach is perhaps to use regular expressions. Besides that, you have to go through code review. `strtok` is dangerous, better to use `strsep` for example...

Comment: "I get error." What error?

Comment: @0andriy thanks for the advice

Comment: @RadLexus sorry the error is:Unhandled exception at 0x5b37d540 (msvcr100d.dll) in abc.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: Second and subsequent calls to "strtok (such as when you call it at the bottom of the while loop) should pass NULL as the first arg - ie.  strtok(NULL, substr) - and don't forget it can return NULL, so you wouldn't want to call strlen on it ! (in fact, that might also be the cause of your access violation)

Comment: @racraman the second strtok is for the token, in the first strtok i get "aa ****", so i call strtok with "aa ****" and " "(space) parameter

Comment: @user5742600, this is exactly the problem with **non-reentrant** `strtok`.

Comment: I solve it, just change to strtok(NULL, subStr) as @racraman advise. thanks guys.